# Effect of Reduce Person on a Large character

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, creature-size

I am naturally large from using the [race builder](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedRaceGuide/raceBuilder/racialQualities.html#size-quality), this gives me

> Large (7 RP): Prerequisite: Humanoids taking this quality must have the giant subtype; Benefit: Large creatures gain a ***+2 size bonus to Strength and a –2 size penalty to Dexterity***. Large races take a –1 size penalty to their AC, a –1 size penalty on attack rolls, a +1 bonus on combat maneuver checks and to their CMD, and a –4 size penalty on Stealth checks. A Large creature takes up a space that is 10 feet by 10 feet and has a reach of 5 feet.

If I were to be under the effect of [Reduce Person](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/reduce-person), what exactly would my size modifiers be?

> This spell causes instant diminution of a humanoid creature, halving its height, length, and width and dividing its weight by 8. This decrease changes the creature's size category to the next smaller one. The target gains a ***+2 size bonus to Dexterity, a -2 size penalty to Strength*** (to a minimum of 1), and a +1 bonus on attack rolls and AC due to its reduced size.

My first thought would be that they are added together and thus cancel each other out because medium creatures have no size bonus, but I've heard that's wrong. What's the net effect?

Comment: I've edited your question for clarity. Please feel free to re-edit or revert if I've inadvertently changed the meaning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Stacking):

> Stacking
>
> Stacking refers to the act of adding together bonuses or penalties
>   that apply to one particular check or statistic. Generally speaking,
>   most bonuses of the same type do not stack. Instead, only the highest
>   bonus applies. Most penalties do stack, meaning that their values are
>   added together. Penalties and bonuses generally stack with one
>   another, meaning that the penalties might negate or exceed part or all
>   of the bonuses, and vice versa.

So your total size modifier bonus would be +0 str and +0 dex.  (in effect giving you +2 dex and -2 str from your normal).  Basically, in terms of reduce person, go by the spell's explicit definition to give you your actual modifiers from the norm, including the bonus to attack and AC.

Comment: Interestingly, reduce size doesn't explicitly modify your CMB, CMD, or Stealth checks, so even when reduced you would keep those penalties and bonuses, even though the stats, ac and to-hit cancel each other.

Comment: @GreySage CMB, CMD, Stealth, to-hit, and AC modifiers are properties of _being_ a given size category, not something that can differ depending on which effect gave you the size. (unlike ability scores.)

Comment: Thanks for that ruling about stacking. I didnt know about that it existed in the rules like that. I need to consider how exactly I will redo my character excel sheet based on this, but its not hard, just need the best method.